# LNK2019 Error: unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors

I am getting an error in Visual Studio when compiling my program.

> Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl
>   Grid::Grid(void)" (??0Grid@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function
>   main  Grid    C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\Dev\Grid\Grid\main.obj    1
>
> Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall
>   Grid::~Grid(void)" (??1Grid@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function
>   _main Grid    C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\Dev\Grid\Grid\main.obj    1

This project works fine at my university but not on my own computer and I am not sure what is wrong.

My main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Grid.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int args, char **argv)
{
   Grid grid;
// grid.LoadGrid("Grid1.txt");
// grid.SaveGrid("OutGrid.txt");

   system("pause");
}
```

And my header file:

```
#pragma once

class Grid
{
public:
    Grid();
    ~Grid();

    void LoadGrid(const char filename[]);
    void SaveGrid(const char filename[]);

private:
    int m_grid[9][9];
};
```

Any help at all is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You have not implemented the members of your Grid class that you promised. Where is your `Grid.cpp`?

Comment: ***This project works fine at my university***  It should not. Well as presented in the question it should not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved from advise given on [[error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall : constructor issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28653316/error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-public-thiscall-constructor-issu][1])

"First in the library project do rightclick->properties, then under the tab General, Configuration Type should be Static library (.lib)."

Thanks everyone for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding your grid class constructor and destractor implementation are missing. You should check your .cpp file, implemention like this

```
Grid(){}
~ Grid(){}
```

Comment: His declaration is fine, it's the definition that is missing. Your suggestion changes a declaration into a definition.